# How to display a message when listview is empty?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to android programming. Here is my code. Kindly help.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
           {

        ListView view = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarms,container, false);
        String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu_list);
        view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, titles));
        view.setAdapter(mAdapter.setCurrentSeverityAlarm(0));
        mListView = view;
        mAdapter.refresh(mSpinnerAdapter);
        return view;
       }
```

**xml file**:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_alarms"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/alarm_list_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/alarm_list_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/alarm_list_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/alarm_list_vertical_margin"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/alarm_list_divider_height"
android:scrollbars="none">
</ListView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a message when the list view is empty in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199904/how-to-display-a-message-when-the-list-view-is-empty-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

ListView has a [`setEmptyView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) method. The View you pass into this method will automatically be shown if your list is empty.

The easiest way to do this is to include the empty View in your layout. Your XML and Java will end up looking something like this:

XML

```
<ListView ... />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nothing to show" />
```

Java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarms,container, false);
    ListView view = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_arlams);
    View emptyView = layout.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

    // ...

    view.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    return layout;
}
```

You can of course also programmatically instantiate a View if you want to keep it out of your XML, or you could use a separate layout file for your empty View.

Comment: How to use a separate layout file for empty view?? How to integrate that in the program?

Comment: You can inflate a second layout using the same inflater. It would look like this: `View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_empty_view, container, false);`

Comment: View layout = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_alarms,container, false);
ListView view = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_alarms);   View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emptyview, container, false);
view.setEmptyView(emptyView);
String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu_list);
view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, titles));
view.setAdapter(mAdapter.setCurrentSeverityAlarm(0));
mListView = view;
mAdapter.refresh(mSpinnerAdapter); return layout;

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Does it show nothing, does it crash, or does it show the wrong thing?

Comment: when the list view is empty, the message in the emptyview is not being displayed

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. The empty View still needs to be in the layout somewhere. Try attaching to the container like this: `View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emptyview, container, true);`

Comment: When I attach the emptyview to the container it displays the message when the listview is empty but it doesn't display the listview content when the listview is not empty

Comment: I would start by including the empty view in your layout with your ListView. Once you have that working satisfactorily, try moving it to a separate layout file. Including it in with the ListView is far more common in my experience.